# ClassNotFoundException: com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.LinkedInApiJaxbClient

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am new in Android development. We have requirement to share content using Linked In in Android. I integrated the code from "https://github.com/mukesh4u/Android-LinkedIn-Demo" link.
I am not able to login using LinkedIn.
Below is the error message show :

LinkedinSample: error to get verifier
System.err: com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClientException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.LinkedInApiJaxbClient
System.err: at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClientFactory.createLinkedInApiClient

I would be thankful if anyone have solution for the same issue.

Thanks,
Datta

Comment: Go to your project structure and in your project module go to dependencies - do you have the linkdn lib added there?

Comment: Thanks for the help.